# No module named '_jpype' in lambda function

Tags: java, python-3.x

I'm trying use the java library in my python code using jypye, its working fine in my local, but when i try to implement that in aws lambda function, im getting an Module error as No module named '_jpype'

My lambda function's deployment package structure is as follows:[deployment package structure phto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFcCr.png)

Can someone help to resolve this